# How do I get this ruby on rails app to copy a file to my hard drive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file coming into my rails app from another website. The POST data looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa03cf0c8d0 @original_filename="Georgia.svg", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Georgia.svg\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/g0/m3jlqvpd4cbc3khznvn5c_7m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130507-52672-1sw119a>>, "originalFileName"=>"Georgia.ttf"}
```

My controller code is this:

```
def target     
  @incoming_file = params[:file]
  file_name = params[:originalFileName]
  File.open("/Users/my_home_directory/#{file_name}", "w+b") {|f| f.write(@thing)} 
end
```

Right now, I can create a file on my hard drive that contains a line of text that shows the object.

This is the code from the file created in my hard drive.

```
<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa03cd1c318>
```

I can write a file with the name of the uploaded file.
I can't seem to figure out how to write the data from the file to my drive. I'm new to ruby on rails. Help me see what I'm missing.
Thx.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Obvious solution would be the one suggested by Richie Min, but it is a bad solution in terms of memory usage, which might get critical if you start uploading large files. Since

```
File.open(...) {|f| f.write(@incoming_file.read)}
```

reads whole uploaded file in memory with `@incoming_file.read`. Better option would be:

```
def target
  @incoming_file = params[:file]
  file_name = params[:originalFileName]
  FileUtils.mv @incoming_file.tempfile, "/Users/my_home_directory/#{file_name}"
end
```

Uploaded data is always stored in temporary files, and `UploadedFile.read` is actually just a proxy to actual File object, which is accessible trough `UploadedFile.tempfile`. This, however, could also be not the best solution if temporary folder and destination directory are on different partitions or even on different disk drives, but still much better than reading the whole file in memory in Rails controller.

You can test it with:

```
curl -X POST -F file=@[some large file] -F originalFileName=somefilename.ext http://[your url]
```

Comment: Using cp instead of mv worked for me and takes out any issue with partitions.  I surmise that mv would handle it fine if they were on separate partions, though.

Answer (score 1):

use

`File.open("/Users/my_home_directory/#{file_name}", "w+b") {|f| f.write(@incoming_file.read)}`